# How can I make my mesh bend joints with my bones?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, vertex-weights

I'm pretty new to Blender. I would like to bend the arm joint with the bones but the mesh will not. I feel like I've tried everything (as shown in the photos below). I have the same problems with the legs, fingers, and spine, they will not bend.

[image: paint weight]

[image: vertex]

[image: normal arm]

[image: wont bend]

Comment: Switch to Pose mode.

Comment: When i go to pose mode the bone loose their connection to each other, so far object mode is the only thing that at least lets the bones connect to things. but maybe I'm not doing it right?

Comment: You need to apply the scale of your armature (Ctrl A in Object mode), maybe also recalculate the normals, and you need to correct the weights for the forearm: Remove its vertices from all vertex groups then paint in Weight Paint mode

Comment: It seems that when i try to apply scale the entire mesh and bones go all wacky and weird.

Comment: The the mesh topology of the elbow and the forearm does not look good. At the elbow it's too dense and it is not evenly distributed on the forearm. Have a look here for base meshes with a clean topology: https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/. Consider a retopology or use the base meshes to fit your design or re-create it from the scratch and use yours as design template.Here are some tips about character modelling for animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01WQlMD7dsk&list=PLL3OEv6vd5VA4owAPOI0QdCcEmvl1f3BT

Comment: Did you the weight paint manually or have you used automatic weights? The latter has problems calculating the weights when there are several mesh parts that are not connected.

Comment: I painted the weights, I think I'll start from scratch, I just didn't really want to cause I still gotta animate it and I don't a bunch of time :( Thank you for the tutorial links.

Comment: 1) Reset transforms on armature.  2) Unparent arm with keep transform.  3) Parent arm to armature with "armature deform" (not bone parent.)  Notice: arm now has an armature modifier.  Now it should be working.  If not, need a file to say anything.

Comment: To fix the topology you can select the edge loops with ALT+click and remove them with key X > *Dissolve Edge* in *Edit* mode. In *Sculpt* mode, use the *Smooth* brush with a low strength (~0.15) to evenly distribute the edge loops with it.

Comment: please share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It looks like your bones are separated. They must be connected as a single armature. In my opinion, you must study rigging deeply to understand the concepts. Good luck.